# Refactoring promise to return from function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I am using JSZip to unzip a directory, which runs async.  I want to write a function that unzips a file and returns the files associated with it, like this:

```
function unzipFile(filename){
  const zipper = new jsZip()
  return fs.readFile(filename, function(err, data) {
    return jsZip.loadAsync(data).then(function(zip) {
      return zip.files
    })
  })
}
```

but this is just return `undefined`.  How can I make this async so that it returns the unzipped directory in a single function, and if I wanted to set a variable equal to its output would await its completion?

Comment: because returning in a regular callback (which you don't do either) has no effect

Comment: you're not even using `zipper` - so, fundamentals are wrong anyway

Comment: It's not possible. Learn to get comfortable with callbacks. You can use async/await keywords as syntax sugar for promises to make it LOOK like you're returning values but at some level an async function still return a promise so at some point you need to deal with callbacks anyway. I personally **strongly** recommend that people don't use async/await until they understand callbacks and promises.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to promisify `fs.readFile` first - then just a regular Promise chain should do the trick

e.g.

```
function unzipFile(filename){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => fs.readFile(filename, function(err, data) {
        if(err) {
            return reject(err);
        }
        resolve(data);
    }))
    .then(data => new jsZip().loadAsync(data))
    .then(zip => zip.files);
}
```

Comment: if the ES2015 "arrow functions" trip you up, you can always run the code through a transpiler like babel :p

Comment: nope, that's pretty much what my linter tells me to do

Answer (score 1):

You will need to [promisify](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572) `fs.readFile`:

```
function readFileAsync(filename) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.readFile(filename, function(err, data) {
            if (err) reject(err);
            else resolve(data);
        });
    });
}
```

Then you can chain onto that:

```
async function unzipFile(filename) {
    const zipper = new jsZip();
    const data = await readFileAsync(filename);
    const zip = await zipper.loadAsync(data);
    return zip.files;
}
```